# What is inverse proportionality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Translated from danish:

> This musical instrument consists of some pipes that have different lengths, and that each has its own tone. The frequency of the tone is inversely proportional to the pipes length. A pipe with the length of 9,4cm has a tone with frequency 880 Hz.
>
> a) How long does a pipe have to be to have a frequency of 588 Hz?

So far I have thought to do the following:

- I do not know where to start, it's a topic I don't understand how to solve.

Comment: im new, sorry if the question title is too broad

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Questions with titles such as "Homework Help" won't be received well. Instead, try to make the title something that references what you are asking. Second, can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: $(1)$ Change the question title to something which actually describes the problem.  $(2)$ Edit into the question any ideas *you have*.

Comment: please read the updated question and title

Answer (score 2):

When we describe a relationship between two variables $x$ and $y$ as being "inversely proportional", we mean that they have a relationship like $$y=\frac kx\tag{inversely proportional}$$  where $k$ is just a constant called, unimaginatively, the "constant of proportionality".  Compare this to a "directly proportional" relationship $$y=kx\tag{directly proportional}$$

So in your problem if $L$ is the length of the pipe and $F$ is the frequency it produces then the relationship between them should be $$L=\frac kF$$ for some $k$.  By giving us one length with its associated frequency, the question is giving us a way to figure out what the value of $k$ should be.  We just plug in the $L$ and $F$ it gives us and solve for $k$:  $$9,4 = \frac{k}{800} \implies k = 9,4\times 800 = 7520$$  Knowing this we can solve the problem.  It asks us to find the length of the pipe $L$ when $F=588$.  So now we just plug in the $k$ value we found and the $F$ value it gives us to get $$L= \frac{7520}{588} \approx \require{enclose}\enclose{roundedbox}{12.789\text{ cm}}$$